# Python: Is date in a Pandas column an options expiry day?

Tags: python, pandas, trading

I am trying to build a function that determines if the date in on column (format is yyyy-mm-dd) is a Monday, Wednesday, Friday or a holiday.  When there is a holiday on the M/W/F, the option expires the day prior.  For all items that resolve True, I would like to create a new column called "Expiry Day" that has True populated.  I am indifferent as to whether the other cells are blank or False (should I care?). I have been trying with the .isoweekday() function, but I am getting an error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isoweekday'.

Here is the code I am using:

```
#set new dataframe
cs_win_loss_df = spx_df['Date']
#cs_win_loss_df['Expiry Day'] = []
#print(cs_win_loss_df)

#determine if day is an expiry day
def expiry_day(df):
    if spx_df['Date'].isoweekday() == 1 or spx_df['Date'].isoweekday() == 3 or spx_df['Date'].isoweekday() == 5 or ((spx_df['Date'].isoweekday() -1 == 5) and (spx_df['Date'].isoweekday() +1 == 3)) or ((spx_df['Date'].isoweekday() -1 == 3) and (spx_df['Date'].isoweekday() +1 == 1)):
        cs_win_loss_df['Trading Days'] = True
        return cs_win_loss_df['Trading Days']

#print(spx_df['Date'].dtype)  
cs_win_loss_df = expiry_day(spx_df)
```

My date list does not have Saturdays or Sundays in it - or the actual holidays.

Appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: Please include a sample of your dataframe along with the expected output. How do you define what a "holiday" is?

Comment: Hi @not_speshal holidays for markets are determined on their websites.  NYSE is an example.  SPX options have this calendar: https://www.cboe.com/about/hours/us-options/

Comment: Add a sample of `spx_df` along with what you want the output to be?

Comment: Here is a print of the current `spx_df`.  What I would like is a new dataframe that shows the date column and then True for dates where there is an options expiration, and False for dates where there is no expiration.
`
Date  Close/Last     Open     High      Low  Put Strike Just Otm  \
0    2011-08-08     1119.46  1198.48  1198.48  1119.28                 1195
1    2011-08-09     1172.53  1120.23  1172.88  1101.54                 1120
2    2011-08-10     1120.76  1171.77  1171.77  1118.01                 1170
3    2011-08-11     1172.64  1121.30  1186.29  1121.30                 1120`

Comment: @MatthewFlynn please add that to your question in proper formatting, so it would be easier to find that data and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a function to determine the market is open or closed given a date:

first you need to install the holidays module: `pip install holidays`

```
#import the holidays module
import pandas as pd
import holidays

#retrieve the holidays for a country i.e. U.S. Holidays:

us_holidays = holidays.UnitedStates(years=2021)


df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("2021-01-01", periods=365, freq="D"), columns=['Date'])
```

it give us a dataframe with 365 rows, each with a day of the year:

output:

```
        Date
0   2021-01-01
1   2021-01-02
2   2021-01-03
3   2021-01-04
4   2021-01-05
... ...
360 2021-12-27
361 2021-12-28
362 2021-12-29
363 2021-12-30
364 2021-12-31
```

then we write a function to apply it to the data frame:

```
def expiration_days(date):
    if date in (us_holidays) or date.dayofweek in ([5,6]):
        return 'Expired'
    else: return 'Not Expired'

#Applying the function to the 'Date' column:
    
df['Expiration_status'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: expiration_days(x))
```

Output:

```
Date    Expiration_status
0   2021-01-01  Expired
1   2021-01-02  Expired
2   2021-01-03  Expired
3   2021-01-04  Not Expired
4   2021-01-05  Not Expired
... ... ...
360 2021-12-27  Not Expired
361 2021-12-28  Not Expired
362 2021-12-29  Not Expired
363 2021-12-30  Not Expired
364 2021-12-31  Expired
```

Comment: Hi Jorge.  Thanks.  But the US holidays file has holidays that the market doesn't celebrate, and vice versa.  For example, Good Friday - the markets are closed.  However, it is not a federal holiday- but I do see it listed.  The market holidays/options expiry dates are here: https://www.cboe.com/about/hours/us-options/

Answer (score 0):

The pandas_market_calendars package is a collection of stock market calendars from all over the world. It includes dates that specific markets are open, the open and closing times, pre-market and after-market open and closing times, etc.

You could check whether a specific date is an open day on the market using NYSE.valid_days, as in the example code below:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas_market_calendars as market_calendar

nyse = market_calendar.get_calendar('NYSE')

print('NYSE schedule for the next 7 days')
print(nyse.schedule(start_date = date.today(), end_date = date.today()+timedelta(7)))

print('\nNYSE open market days in the first week of March')
print(nyse.valid_days(start_date='2022-3-1', end_date='2022-03-7'))

check_open = nyse.valid_days(start_date=date.today(),end_date=date.today())

if check_open.empty:
    print('\n Market is closed today' )
else:
    print('\n Market is open today')
```

output:

```
NYSE schedule for the next 7 days
                         market_open              market_close
2022-01-03 2022-01-03 14:30:00+00:00 2022-01-03 21:00:00+00:00
2022-01-04 2022-01-04 14:30:00+00:00 2022-01-04 21:00:00+00:00
2022-01-05 2022-01-05 14:30:00+00:00 2022-01-05 21:00:00+00:00
2022-01-06 2022-01-06 14:30:00+00:00 2022-01-06 21:00:00+00:00
2022-01-07 2022-01-07 14:30:00+00:00 2022-01-07 21:00:00+00:00

NYSE open market days in the first week of March
DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-01 00:00:00+00:00', '2022-03-02 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2022-03-03 00:00:00+00:00', '2022-03-04 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2022-03-07 00:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq=None)

The market is closed today
```